# Rails email isn't showing logo inline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, email-attachments

I have a Rails app that generates invoices.  I want our company logo to appear inline on the invoice email.

It looks fine onscreen.

But, the logo "AME_logo.gif" shows up as an attachment to the email instead of showing up in-line.

My invoice_mailer.rb has:

```
attachments.inline['AME_Logo.gif'] = File.read('app/assets/images/AME_Logo.gif')
```

My _invoice_email.html.erb has:

```
<td><%= image_tag("AME_Logo.gif") %></td>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image_tag should be:

`<%= image_tag attachments["AME_Logo.gif"].url %>`

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods especially section 2.3.2 Making Inline Attachments.

Comment: I get `undefined local variable or method "attachments" for #`

Comment: I'm using PaperClip for attachments. I wonder if that's causing the issue?

Comment: That should not be the problem. I assume that `_invoice_email.html.erb` is a mailer template, right? Otherwise indeed the `attachments` method would not be defined.

Comment: `_invoice_email.html.erb` is a partial.  It used in an online view and the mailer = `invoice_email.html.erb`

Comment: Is there a way to render the invoice on another view page without it being a file that starts with a dash?

Comment: I moved the image tag to the `invoice_email.html.erb` page from the partial.